# Javascript:Window.prompt How to turn it on in Windows Phone

Tags: javascript, windows-phone-8

Using the `window.prompt()` for user input of a single string seemed very efficient given its cross-browser functionality but at hind sight it does not seem that likely any more. I realize of course IE 7 and 8 had `window.prompt()` [disabled by default](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms536673%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) but could be enabled through the content settings but how to do the same on a windows phone? I've checked the IE settings and System Settings and couldn't find any.

Comment: I'm curious, why was this even disabled by default to begin with?

Comment: Microsoft says, in the link referred in my question, `This helps prevent malicious sites from initiating spoofing attacks` but I just think Microsoft is yapping just because they can't provide the same security as other browsers do without removing features :/. And even more, IE 11 has it enabled by default.